# Batch File Not Running Code

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a simple batch file that runs a program that depends on what chapter is entered. When I run my code:

```
set foundChap=0
set/p chap=Enter Chapter Number:
if (%chap%==021) (
 set foundChap=1
 START C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe
) else (
 echo Chapter file not found.
)
PAUSE
```

All it does is echo the code, doesn't run anything. Any ideas? This is my first time trying to make a batch file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without additional comments as every syntax error is documented already hundreds of times on Stack Overflow.

```
@echo off
set foundChap=0
set /p "chap=Enter Chapter Number: "
if "%chap%"=="021" (
   set foundChap=1
   start "Paint" "C:\Windows\system32\mspaint.exe"
) else (
   echo Chapter file not found.
)
pause
```

I add a comment:

`set /?` displays help for command `set`.
`if /?` displays help for command `if`.
`start /?` displays help for command `start`.

Do you understand the logic on how to get help and read before ask?

Comment: Thank you for your help. "Do you understand the logic on how to get help and read before ask?" I have never used batch before and this is all new to me, but I get how to find help now. Thanks again.